# AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'origin_set'

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I'm writing a script to create a cubical object out of several joined planes. After joining the meshes into one object (`shadow_catcher`), I need to set its origin to center of mass, so I call the following commands:

[image]

```
bpy.ops.object = bpy.data.objects["shadow_catcher"]
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'origin_set'
```

Strangely, this operation does work using the GUI. I have been searching for a solution for hours but alas no luck.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first line, you need set the active object, not `bpy.ops.object`. You also need to select the object.

```py
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["shadow_catcher"]
bpy.data.objects["shadow_catcher"].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')
```

Comment: Works! Thank you